# DirectShow - changing white balance property

Tags: windows, video, webcam, directshow

I am capturing data from the web camera by using DirectShow api. To change white balance value I call `IAMVideoProcAmp::Set` method. 
I have noticed that for some cameras white balance value is being changed immediately (after 1-2 frames new values is already applied). But for other cameras it is being applied incrementally during 50-60 frames. It is too long for me.

May be someone has faced with the same problem. Can I configure how fast new value will be applied or does it depend on the camera's driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IAMVideoProcAmp::Set` is all you have. There is no generic way to change white balance or affect the way changes take effect. If you are interested in specific models of cameras, you might check with tech support if there is SDK available and model-specific ways to setup the device.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your answer.